# Data Structure to implement a Word Dictionary

Tags: algorithm, dictionary, data-structures, hashmap, mapping

Recently, I was asked in an interview about the usage of data structure.
The question was: what will be the data structure that I will intend to use while creating an English Dictionary. The dictionary will contain number of words under each alphabet and each word will have 1 meaning. Also, how will I implement the data structures to update, search and select different words?

What do you suggest guys? And what is the reason for your suggestion?

Comment: I believe a trie would be the obvious suggestion. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie#Dictionary_representation

Comment: If all you need to do is lookup and update words a hash map would be your best bet. If you also need the functionality "find all words that begin with x" then I would suggest a trie

Comment: A trie is horribly memory inefficient.

Comment: @YvesDaoust how so? With a data-set as large as a dictionary, trie would be efficient in every way. Also, in a dictionary, the way we look-up words is character by character, and this type of search is pretty efficient with trie.

Comment: @vish4071: I said memory inefficient.

Comment: Yes...but for large data, it is memory efficient too, isn't it?

Comment: @vish4071: why should it ? Every node takes like 26 pointers, so at least 500 bytes per word. And kilobytes for long words.

Comment: No, not every node is 26 pointers. Every level can be implemented with 26 pointers. Think about it. @YvesDaoust

Comment: @vish4071: I wonder how you will access 100000 words with 26 pointers...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A hash table would be the preferred data structure to implement a dictionary with update, search and selection capabilities.

A hash table is a data structure that can store key-value pairs. It is essentially an array containing all of the keys to search on. A hash function(***h()***) is used to compute an index into an array in which an element can be inserted or searched. So when insertion is required, the hash function is used to find the location where the element needs to be inserted.

Insertion under reasonable assumptions is ***O(1)***. Each time we insert data, it takes ***O(1)*** time to insert it (assuming the hash function is ***O(1)***).

Looking up data is also similar. If we need to find a the meaning of the word ***x***, we need to calculate ***h(x)***, this would tell us where ***x*** is located in the hash table. So we can look up words (hash values) in ***O(1)*** as well.

However, ***O(1)*** insertion and search do not always hold true. There is nothing which guarantees that the hash function won't produce the same output for two different inputs, consequently there would be a collision. In order to handle this scenario various strategies can be employed, namely *separate chaining* and *open addressing*. But the search/insertion would no longer be ***O(1)***.